# JSON Traversing to element using Json webservices in android

Tags: android, web-services, json

I am taking result of a json webservice in JSONObject. While printing this jsonObject it is printing exact result. I got problem at the time of fetching values in this result because i am reading a complex response that is in the form of

```
{"FoodMenuRS"
:{"Status":"Success",
 "TotalResults":2,
"Results":{"Items":
{"Item":[
{"@Id":"6","@Name":"Tea"},
{"@Id":"4","@Name":"Coffee"}
]}}}}
```

Here i am reading through,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("Item");
```

Here i am getting error "No Value for Item"

Where as i got fetched value while calling another service which is simple in format,

```
{"earthquakes":
[{"eqid":"c0001xgp","magnitude":8.8,"lng":142.369,"src":"us","datetime":"2011-03-11 04:46:23","depth":24.4,"lat":38.322},
{"eqid":"2010xkbv","magnitude":7.5,"lng":91.9379,"src":"us","datetime":"2010-06-12 17:26:50","depth":35,"lat":7.7477}]}
```

I called it using,

```
JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");
```

Please help how to fetch this type of Json response. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

ya it is very complex but i refer you to use Gson library to parse Json as it is parse in structural manner **[example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
        private String jString = "{\"menu\": {\"id\": \"file\", \"value\": \"File\", \"popup\": { \"menuitem\": [ {\"value\": \"New\",   \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"}, {\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"}, {\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}]}}}";

        JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");
        String attributeId = menuObject.getString("id");
        String attributeValue = menuObject.getString("value");
        JSONObject popupObject = menuObject.getJSONObject("popup");
        JSONArray menuitemArray = popupObject.getJSONArray("menuitem");
```

With every new curley braces call getJSONObjectand for child call getString.

Or you can follow Gson concept to fetch response.

Answer (score 0):

Done with

```
    JSONObject menuObject = jObject.getJSONObject("menu");
    String attributeValue = menuObject.getString("value");
```